# Can we get UID of nfc tag using nfc_manager

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am working on flutter nfc and i found nfc_manager the better package.

I want to know the UID of nfc tag is it possible using nfc_manager

I tried to search but was unable to find one.

If you know how to read or write nfc with would be helpful

Is there any alternate packages?